# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when downloading PDF with POST from ASP.Net Core controller

Tags: http, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, postman

I created an endpoint that takes a json body from a POST request, uses that data to fill in the fields of a PDF, and send the filled out file back. When I try to send a POST request using Send and Download on Postman, I initially get a 200 OK back and Postman goes into a loading state, showing how much time the download has taken so far.
[image: Postman in its download state]

After about 2 minutes of this, I get an ECONNRESET error:
[image: ECONNRESET error and request headers]

Thinking this was just a problem with Postman, I updated a React project of mine to hit the endpoint. I was expecting making the request would start the browser's built in file download feature. Instead, I got a similar error: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
[image: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET]

I debugged my controller and it seems to be parsing the request body correctly. It also doesn't seem to take too long to return from the endpoint's function. I'm using the File method from ControllerBase to make the response from the file stream, and I make sure not to dispose of the file stream too early.

Per Ali Vahidinasab's request, here is the Postman request exported to C#:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://localhost:44398/api/charactersheet/download");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/pdf");
            var body = @"{
" + "\n" +
            @"    ""abilityScores"": {
" + "\n" +
            @"        ""strength"": 10,
" + "\n" +
            @"        ""dexterity"": 11,
" + "\n" +
            @"        ""constitution"": 12,
" + "\n" +
            @"        ""intelligence"": 13,
" + "\n" +
            @"        ""wisdom"": 14,
" + "\n" +
            @"        ""charisma"": 15
" + "\n" +
            @"    }
" + "\n" +
            @"}";
            request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine($"Status Code: {response.StatusCode}");
```

When I ran this client code, the response had a status code of 0, which I understand means that there is no response from the server.

I guess the crux of this question is: is this an issue with the server or the client? And what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Please create a simple console application and use postman code export to easily create and test the request using c#, then if your problem persists update your question with exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. It was on the server side. I had to set the position of the memory stream I was returning to 0 before returning it.